# Cannot get Interaction using Fuel REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, fuel

The [getInteractionById](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionById.html) method results in a 404 error when using the documented request:

```
HOST: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
GET /interaction/v1/interactions/interactions/{id}
Content-Type: application/json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the documentation is incorrect. If I change the path from:

```
/interaction/v1/interactions/interactions/{id}
```

To:

```
/interaction/v1/interactions/{id}
```

Then my request works correctly. Looks like the documentation needs to be fixed.

Comment: Actually, I've just realized that **all Interaction methods** are documented incorrectly. You need to replace any instance of `/interactions/interactions` with `/interactions`

Comment: I see the docs are updated now. Thanks for clearing up the confusion.