# Fuel API (Python) Starting an Interaction (Program)

Tags: rest-api, fuel, python

I'm currently in the research phase of which API will suite our needs, one of which is starting a Program (which will likely contain a transfer step, import step, user initiated send step).  In a previous implementation (prior employer) we accomplished this with the SOAP XML API (Perl) without issue.

In reading through the documentation of the Fuel API, I fail to see this specific Interaction supported, but I would have thought this to be one of the first to be implemented.

Can anyone advise if I'm simply overlooking this in the documentation, can it be done, or should this be filed as an enhancement request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed supported. The correct URL is

```
/interaction/v1/interactions/{id}
```

There was a bug in the official documentation which should now be fixed. Refer [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63418/cannot-get-interaction-using-fuel-rest-api) thread for more details.